# Parsing data out of a multiple nested webpages

Tags: parsing, web-crawler, html-parsing

Basically we have a website that has a bunch of data on different items and it is arranged to be able to describe an item in a tree like structure (http://www.isoldwhat.com/getcats/fullcategorytree.php). We want to break all the categories out and export them to a Json file. The problem I am having is that to open each category I need to click it and let it reload. I guess I have to emulate clicks through each category.  What would be the best approach to parsing this data out?  I was probably going to use some jQuery, but I'm open to other options.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to options then I would use [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). I used it for a project where I had to scrape data on a web page and store it and write reports against it. I too had to emulate real user navigation and this is perfect for it. It's documentation is pretty straightforward. It's easy to get started with. In a half hour I was scraping results from a simple search page.

I also used [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) For parsing certain data. The combination of these two should pretty much get you where you want to go.